# Angular 2's named router outlet cannot be found?

Tags: angularjs, angular2-routing

I have a main app.component file which redirects to a login file. I want to have named router outlets throughout the app because I need to navigate to full page views in different places in the app. Unfortunately, the redirect doesn't work and angular complains that

> RROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'

Here's the code

```
    nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <p class="text-primary">
          <strong> Zuora Ecommerce Portal </strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li>
        <a href="#Login">
          <strong>Login</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#Your Info"><strong>Account Information</strong></a></li>
      <li><a href="#inv"><strong>Billing and Payments</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="main"></router-outlet>
```

And here's the routing config:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {Login} from "./login.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login',  component: Login, outlet:'main'},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: change redirectTo: '/login' to redirectTo: 'login'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your default route like below,

```
...
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/(main:login)', pathMatch: 'full' },
...
```

Check this [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/ytIHnbFcyCFbJRfcAmQ5?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!